# Issues with cdn.sstatic.net - HTTP 409 returned

Tags: bug, status-declined, cdn, cloudflare

We are getting layout problems on stackoverflow from our location since a while now. When we trace down the issue we saw that all resources from cdn.sstatic.net (e.g. CSS files) returns with HTTP 409.

e.g. when you call http://stackoverflow.com the following resource returns a HTTP 409: http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=334b440f2d56

When we then try to call that resource manually we get a page from CloudFlare which tells us that there is a problem with DNS resolution.
Further information:
Error 1001 Ray ID: 2f0b72068497274a • 2016-10-12 15:04:38 UTC 
DNS resolution error

Regards

Markus

Comment: We haven't used CloudFlare in quite some time (we use Fastly now). Your DNS is outdated and not resolving to the correct place to get resources.

Comment: It's not our DNS it's the google DNS which returns the Cloudflare addresses: 
`> cdn.sstatic.net
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    cdn.sstatic.net
Addresses:  151.101.1.69
          151.101.65.69
          151.101.193.69
          151.101.129.69`

Comment: Looks like you are using route 53 from AWS for DNS. Could there be an issue for our region?